# Does an iOS app with background audio run when not playing audio?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9

Does an iOS app which declares using background audio run indefinitely?  Or, is its lifecycle tied to `AVAudioSession` being active?  Or, is it tied to audio playback being active?

I want to know what happens when you stop audio in a background app.  Is the app then eligible for termination?

I'm only interested in iOS 8 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple docs are saying:

> When the UIBackgroundModes key contains the audio value, the system’s
>   media frameworks automatically prevent the corresponding app from
>   being suspended when it moves to the background. As long as it is
>   playing audio or video content or recording audio content, the app
>   continues to run in the background. However, if recording or playback
>   stops, the system suspends the app.

[More details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I looked in all sorts of iOS programming books for the answer, but didn't think to check Apple's docs.